# Android: Setting time in time picker with the time shown in text view

Tags: android, time, android-timepicker

In my app, I am showing time in text view as 07:00 PM. On click of the text view, a time picker dialog pops up, In that time picker, I have to show exactly the same time as what is appearing in textview. But, I am not getting how to do that.

**CODE**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
        //int hr = 0;
        Date date = null;
        try 
        {
            date = sdf.parse(resDateArray[3]);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        //tp is reference variable for time picker

        tp.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        tp.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        }//else
```

Comment: refer this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use a `SimpleDateFormat` to get a `Date` object from your `String`.
Then just call

```
picker.setCurrentHour(date.getHours())
```

and

```
picker.setCurrentMinute(date.getMinutes())
```

Since the `Date` object is deprecated, you should use a `Calendar` instead of it.
You can instantiate a `Calendar` this way:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
picker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
picker.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendat.MINUTE));
```

Edit: the complete code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; //Don't use "android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat"
import java.text.ParseException; //Don't use "android.net.ParseException"

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse("07:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);

TimePicker picker = new TimePicker(getApplicationContext());
picker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
picker.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: Did it, but time I am showing is PM. So, how can show the time in AM/PM?

Comment: With the SimpleDateFormat, you can use a format String that allow for using "AM/PM" date format. Like : 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:ss a");
    date = sdf.parse("07:00 AM");
    Then use Calendar.HOUR instead of Calendat.HOUR_OF_DAY in order to get AM/PM hour format

Comment: You should use "hh:mm a" instead of "HH:mm a" because "HH" represents the hour in day (0-23). Take a look at the doc below : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem actually, I was doing it in wrong way.

Comment: The `setCurrent...` methods are deprecated since API 23, use `setHour` & `setMinute` instead!

Answer (score 4):

If anybody using the following format that is without using timepicker widget use this one..

```
mStartTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new TimePickerDialog(AddAppointmentActivity.this, onStartTimeListener, calendar
                    .get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();

        }
    });

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onStartTimeListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String AM_PM;
        int am_pm;

        mStartTime.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute + "  " + AM_PM);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    }
};
```

Comment: AM_PM is not initialized.

Comment: @Apurva see inside time listener ` String AM_PM;`

Answer (score 4):

I have created this helper function to get time

```
        public static void showTime(final Context context, final TextView textView) {

    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String am_pm = "";
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            if (myCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
                am_pm = "AM";
            else if (myCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
                am_pm = "PM";
            String strHrsToShow = (myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ? "12" : myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "";
            //UIHelper.showLongToastInCenter(context, strHrsToShow + ":" + myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + am_pm);
            textView.setText(strHrsToShow + ":" + myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + am_pm);
        }
    };
    new TimePickerDialog(context, mTimeSetListener, myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false).show();
}
```

and How to get current time in required format, I use following code.
                      // PARAM Date is date of time you want to format
                      // PARAM currentFormat of date
                      // PARAM requiredFormat of date

```
    public static String getFormattedDate(String date, String currentFormate, String requiredFormate) {
    //SimpleDateFormat formatActual = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy - MM - dd");
    if (date != null) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatActual = new SimpleDateFormat(currentFormate);
        Date dateA = null;
        try {
            dateA = formatActual.parse(date);
            System.out.println(dateA);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormate);
        String format = formatter.format(dateA);
        System.out.println(format);
        return format;
    } else {
        return "";
    }

}
```

**usage of getFormattedDate is:**

```
       String date = getFormattedDate(dateYouWantToFormate,"hh:mm a","hh:mm");
```

Comment: if i want to set time in hh:mm format then what changes is needed?

Comment: I have edit the answer so you can get in your required format

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the TimePicker nowdays its probably best to check the Build Version as the setCurrentHour and setCurrentMinute has been deprecated.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:ss");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse("07:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);

TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(getApplicationContext());

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    timePicker.setHour(calculateHours());
    timePicker.setMinute(calculateMinutes());
}
else {
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(calculateHours());
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(calculateMinutes());
}
```

Comment: Do you think there is a better way to handle this check? Running this if-else check for every time picker in the app can be tedious

Comment: You could create your own TimePicker class with set hours and minutes methods, then have the class itself handle the logic and assigned the correct one accordingly, another similar option could be extension methods

Comment: Yeah that would work fine. I tried the extension but it seems android studio still produces a warning because it references deprecated code. I guess android studio isn't smart enough to understand we are handling this properly?

Comment: @baskInEminence Another weird thing is that the deprecated functions call the new functions, so it makes this check seem redundant.  
It's really unclear how we should handle it.

Answer (score 2):

One important point has to be kept in mind while retrieving time in `onTimeSet()` function, there is no special function to set `AM_PM` in the calendar instance.
When we set the time `AM_PM` is automatically set accordingly like if AM was selected while choosing hour and minute then `<calendarVariable>.get(Calendar.AM_PM)` will return 0 and in opposite case (in case of PM) it will return 1.

Answer (score 1):

Some changes after sdk version 23;

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse("12:02:32");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(date != null) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(date);
                sleepTimeStartPicker.setHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                sleepTimeStartPicker.setMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For AM/PM you have to implement a logic for that and that is as below.. so you can get the output as you mentioned ... just try below code...

```
int hr=tp.getCurrentHour();
String a="AM";
if(hr>=12){
    hr=hr-12;
    a="PM";
}
String tm=hr+":"+tp.getCurrentMinute()+" "+a;

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tm, 500).show();
```

Comment: But, how can I add AM/PM in time picker

Comment: It's depends on the "Settings"... In the setting go to the Date and Time... after that there is a option "Use 24-hours format"... uncheck it and restart the mobile and reinstall the app...